# Find out file extension from a System.IO.Stream object

Tags: asp.net, file, stream, .net

I have a method which returns a System.IO.Stream object initialized from a file.  I want to assert that the stream object was created for a file with the correct file extension.

Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since your `Stream` object was initialized from a file (hopefully, from a file *name*), it should be a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx). Therefore, you can use its [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.name.aspx) property to obtain the name of the underlying file:

```
FileStream fileStream = yourStream as FileStream;
if (fileStream != null) {
    string extensionWithDot = Path.GetExtension(fileStream.Name);
    // Now test the file extension.
}
```